# AndroidPlot in java android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, androidplot

I have tried the dynamic XY plot AndroidPlot and it is working great but I have one question.
I am using the plot in order to display Gradiac plot of a patient. What parameters do I have to change in order the plot to be displaying exactly as the real doctors cardiac equipments?
for example like this [image](http://www.biopac.com/ProductImages/ecg100c-mri_compare.jpg)
I am getting the plot as wave curve

If anyone has used it and knows anything about this I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Don't really know if I understood your problem but... You're saying you get the plot as wave curve, so I guess you are using the `BeizerLineAndPointFormatter` formatter when creating the series.
If this is the case, then you should use `LineAndPointFormatter` instead, which will draw straight lines in your plot.

Should be something like this:

```
yourPlot.addSeries(yourNumberSerie, new LineAndPointFormatter(lineColor, pointColor, fillColor));
```